# Render reactjs component not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, react-rails

I created a reactjs component by using react-rails gem:

```
@SettingWidget = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      React.DOM.span
        style:
          color: 'red'
        'Hello'
      React.DOM.span
        style:
        color: 'blue'
        'World'
```

In my view:

```
= react_component 'SettingWidget'
```

But I cannot render this component, I'm new in reactjs and rails, many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify any html option for element, put it `{}` like this:

```
@SettingWidget = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div {}, # Check here
      React.DOM.span
        style:
          color: 'red'
        'Hello'
      React.DOM.span
        style:
        color: 'blue'
        'World'
```

Comment: Thanks, how about define an empty `className: ''`, it also works